# Pandas apply, 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, apply

I have the following dataframe :

```
Y = list(range(5))
Z = np.full(5, np.nan)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ColY = Y, ColZ = Z))
print(df)
   ColY  ColZ
0     0   NaN
1     1   NaN
2     2   NaN
3     3   NaN
4     4   NaN
```

And this dictionary :

```
Dict = {
    0 : 1,
    1 : 2,
    2 : 3,
    3 : 2,
    4 : 1
}
```

I would like to fill ColZ with "ok" if corresponding value of ColY through Dict is 2. Consequently, I would like the following dataframe :

```
   ColY ColZ
0     0  NaN
1     1   ok
2     2  NaN
3     3   ok
4     4  NaN
```

I tried this script:

```
df['ColZ'] = df['ColZ'].apply(lambda x : "ok" if Dict[x['ColY']] == 2 else Dict[x['ColY']])
```

I have this error :

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: df['ColZ'] = df['ColY'].apply(lambda x : "ok" if Dict[x] == 2 else np.nan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new Series for compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
df['ColZ'] = np.where(df['ColY'].map(Dict).eq(2), 'ok', np.nan)
print(df)
   ColY ColZ
0     0  nan
1     1   ok
2     2  nan
3     3   ok
4     4  nan
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df['ColY'].map(Dict))
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    2
4    1
Name: ColY, dtype: int64
```

Your solution should be changed with `.get` for return some default value, here `np.nan` if no match:

```
df['ColZ'] = df['ColY'].apply(lambda x : "ok" if Dict.get(x, np.nan) == 2 else np.nan)
```

EDIT: For set working with `df['ColZ']` values use:

```
Y = list(range(5))
Z = list('abcde')
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ColY = Y, ColZ = Z))
print(df)
Dict = {
    0 : 1,
    1 : 2,
    2 : 3,
    3 : 2,
    4 : 1
}

df['ColZ1'] = np.where(df['ColY'].map(Dict).eq(2), 'ok', df['ColZ'])
df['ColZ2'] = df.apply(lambda x : "ok" if Dict.get(x['ColY'], np.nan) == 2 
                                       else x['ColZ'], axis=1)
print (df)
   ColY ColZ ColZ1 ColZ2
0     0    a     a     a
1     1    b    ok    ok
2     2    c     c     c
3     3    d    ok    ok
4     4    e     e     e
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael ! And how could I have the value of ColZ rather than np.nan if the condition Dict.get(x, np.nan) == 2 is False ? In this example, ColZ had only NaN values but in reality, it has real values

Comment: @Ewdlam - Answer was edited, faster solution is with `map`, apply are loops under the hood, so slow